# knockout.js computed value using mapping plugin - inside an array

Tags: knockout.js, mapping, viewmodel

I have the following viewmodel (so far):

```
var TradeViewModel = function (config) {
    var self = this;
    var mapping = {
        'result': {
            'stuff': {
                update: function(options) {
                    return options.data + 'foo!';
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ko.mapping.fromJS(config, mapping, self);
};
```

and my data looks like this:

```
{
  "result": {
    "stuff": [
      {
        "foo": "bar",
        "important": "computeme",
      },
      {
        "foo": "baz",
        "important": "computemetoo",
      }
    ],
    "otherstuff": [
    ]
  }
}
```

The standard documentation that ive seen covers nested associative arrays, but doesnt say much about regular arrays.  In my case, I think I need a function that will iterate over each item in "stuff" and compute the new value, yielding "computemefoo!" and "computemetoofoo!", for example. Im new to knockout, and kind of lost about this one...

jsfiddle:
[Fiddle with me](http://jsfiddle.net/jvsteiner/jpTas/2/)
The base model is in path /2/  You can see what I am trying by incrementing /3/, /4/ etc.

Comment: Added to post as requested - its a good idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I you want to update a value you can just add a function to the viewmodel.

Something like:

```
self.update = function (x){
    return x() + 'foo!';
}
```

From the HTML you can call back to the root of the viewmodel by using `$root`. Which will result in something like:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: result.stuff">
    <li data-bind="text: $root.update(important)"></li>
</ul>
```

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jpTas/8/)

Comment: teh awesome.  I had a feeling I was making it far too complex.